# How to reset github oauth token in composer?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Im having a problem when using composer install because of this

[image]

I tried finding the auth.json file but the credentials don't exist there. How can I reset the GitHub OAuth token in the composer?

Comment: could you please share your composer.json while masking some of your sensitive data?

Comment: Where have you searched? That file could be placed in `~/.composer`

Comment: For me that file was in `/home/username/.config/composer/auth.json`, and contained the `"github-oauth": {"token"}`. After removing the token my issues were gone.

Answer (score 2):

You can run this to reset the GitHub OAuth token in the composer:

```
composer config -g --unset github.oauth.github.com
```

This solved the issue for me.